# How do I disable the gui cursor in insert mode?

Tags: neovim, cursor

I am trying to disable the cursor (`guicursor`) while in insert mode in NeoVim
to emulate a typewriter style environment.

To that effect I set `guicursor` (default is
`vim.opt.guicursor="n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr-o:hor20"` ) to `i:ver0`
and `i:nil`. The first I inferred from the [docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27guicursor%27) while the
latter was a stab in the dark.

Using `i:ver0` returns "invalid percentage," while `i:nil` also outputs an error
message. Neither works.

I asked at [NeoVim's GitHub and they suggested](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/24610#event-10037849756) to [send an event from the UI](https://neovim.io/doc/user/ui.html#ui-global), namely:

> `["busy_start"]` `["busy_stop"]` Indicates to the UI that it must stop rendering
> the cursor. This event is misnamed and does not actually have anything to do
> with busyness.

My issue is I am at a loss as to how to accomplish that. Tried setting the usual
`vim.opt` but they don't seem to take.

Also, if you have any idea on how to trigger that event only when entering
insert mode, it would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've made some small edits, but I don't think neovim.io is the "wiki." Would you mind linking to (a) the page that suggested the default `guicursor` (probably `:help guicursor`?) and (b) the GitHub conversation?

Comment: Added the links. Apologies for not including them right from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- typewriter.lua

local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef([[
void ui_busy_start(void);
void ui_busy_stop(void);
]])

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"InsertEnter"}, {
  callback = function()
    ffi.C.ui_busy_start()
  end
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"InsertLeave"}, {
  callback = function()
    ffi.C.ui_busy_stop()
  end
})
```

Answer provided not by me but by ad-chaos over at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/discussions/24612#discussioncomment-6683538